# Why do I have ParameterResolutionException when I don't even use parametrized test?

Tags: java, junit, junit5, spring-test

I want to write a test for my BookService. This is that test. I don't know why I get the below error all the time:

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: No ParameterResolver registered for parameter 
[com.mrfisherman.library.service.domain.BookService bookService] in constructor 
[public com.mrfisherman.library.service.domain.BookServiceTest(com.mrfisherman.library.service.domain.BookService,
com.mrfisherman.library.persistence.repository.BookRepository)].
```

As you can see I don't use parametrized tests here. Thank you in advance!

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = Server.class)
class BookServiceTest {

    private final BookService bookService;
    private final BookRepository bookRepository;

    public BookServiceTest(BookService bookService, BookRepository bookRepository) {
        this.bookService = bookService;
        this.bookRepository = bookRepository;
    }

    @Test
    void saveBook() {
        //given
        Book book = new Book();
        book.setTitle("Book 1");
        book.setPublishYear(1990);
        book.setType(BookFormat.REAL);
        book.setIsbn("1234567890");
        book.setDescription("Very good book");
        book.setNumberOfPages(190);
        book.setSummary("Very short summary");
        book.setCategories(Set.of(new Category("horror"), new Category("drama")));

        //when
        bookService.saveBook(book);

        //then
        Optional<Book> loaded = bookRepository.findById(book.getId());
        assertThat(loaded).isPresent();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In JUnit Jupiter, a `ParameterResolutionException` is thrown whenever a test class constructor, lifecycle method (such as `@BeforeEach`), or test method declares a parameter that cannot be resolved by one of the registered `ParameterResolver` extensions.

Thus, a `ParameterResolutionException` can be thrown even when you are not using a `@ParameterizedTest` method.

When using `@SpringBootTest`, the `SpringExtension` is automatically registered for you. The `SpringExtension` implements the `ParameterResolver` extension API from JUnit Jupiter so that you can have beans from your `ApplicationContext` injected into constructors and methods in your test class.

The easiest way to solve your issue is to annotate the `BookServiceTest` constructor with `@Autowired`.

For more information and alternative approaches, check out the [Dependency Injection with `SpringExtension`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-junit-jupiter-di) section of the Spring reference docs.

Answer (score 2):

It *is* parameterized. How is the test framework supposed to create a new instance of the `BookServiceTest` class?

Ordinarily, test classes have a no-args constructor (at which point, the framework can just create a new instance without needing any additional information, such as 'how do I obtain an instance of bookService to pass to this constructor?').

Comment: So what I should do now, using @BeforeAll and there put BookService and BookRepository?

Comment: MrFisherman is using Spring. Thus, the last comment is bad advice. In an integration test using Spring Boot, one would rather have the Spring-managed components injected into the test class instance -- for example using `@Autowired`.

Comment: @SamBrannen D'oh, yes, of course - I've deleted my comment (which suggested to use `@Before` method that initializes them).

Answer (score 1):

That error happens on junit5 test with **jboss Weld container** initialization as well. If you don't have an additional annotation on test the **@ParameterizedTest** method fails. Pls use **@ExplicitParamInjection** to fix it.

```
@EnableWeld
@ExplicitParamInjection // that should be put to prevent error in test run
class MyCustomTest {

    @WeldSetup
    public WeldInitiator weld = WeldInitiator.from()...........build();

    @CsvSource(value = {1, 2, 3})
    @ParameterizedTest
    void getEventsByFilter(int inputValue) {
       // do some stuff with inputValue
    }
}
```

}